# Ways or Methods to integrate livestream internally in our application?

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Currently, we have our stable build of Jitsi-Meet, then customized it & added some new features for our target customers. Now we are planning to integrate the Livestream feature into our application. We have found out that Jitsi uses an internal feature called Jibri to record and stream simultaneously but we are looking for alternative solutions other than Jibri.

If there's any method to Livestream internally in our application please let us know
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement and if you don't wanna use jibri you may have to change in jitsi-videobridge codes where you have to add your own logic for sending streams to both end users and livestream server.

But from my knowledge, there is no alternative or better pre-built solution (till today) for this other than jibri and unfortunately we also use jibri for recording in our build. Thanks..!

And you can discuss jitsi related topics in https://community.jitsi.org where you will be able to get help/advice from much more experienced jitsi enthusiasts.